# Invalid Character Creating Container with docker-compose

Tags: docker, docker-compose, mariadb

Running latest version of Docker Desktop on Windows 10 and trying to get PhotoPrism setup after successfully setting up PiGallery2 but wanting something *more*.

This is probably extremely basic and I'm likely a bit in over my head (not a programmer by any means aside from basic logic), but when I run `docker-compose up -d` I pull the files but then I see this:

```
photoprism Pulled
Container -mariadb-1  Creating
Error response from daemon: Invalid container name (-mariadb-1), only [a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9_.-] are allowed
```

From the way I understand it, it's unable to create the container due to the `-` in the name. I just don't really get why it's trying to use "**-mariadb-1**" and as far as I can tell, I'm not seeing anywhere I can tell it to name the container something else.

Here's my docker-compose.yml contents:

```
version: '3.5'

services:
photoprism:
image: photoprism/photoprism:latest
depends_on:
  - mariadb

security_opt:
  - seccomp:unconfined
  - apparmor:unconfined
ports:
  - "2342:2342" # HTTP port (host:container)
environment:
  PHOTOPRISM_ADMIN_PASSWORD: "[redacted]"
  PHOTOPRISM_AUTH_MODE: "password"
  PHOTOPRISM_SITE_URL: "http://localhost:2342/"
  PHOTOPRISM_ORIGINALS_LIMIT: 50000
  PHOTOPRISM_HTTP_COMPRESSION: "gzip"
  PHOTOPRISM_DEBUG: "false"
  PHOTOPRISM_READONLY: "false"
  PHOTOPRISM_EXPERIMENTAL: "false"
  PHOTOPRISM_DISABLE_CHOWN: "false"
  PHOTOPRISM_DISABLE_WEBDAV: "false"
  PHOTOPRISM_DISABLE_SETTINGS: "false"
  PHOTOPRISM_DISABLE_TENSORFLOW: "false"
  PHOTOPRISM_DISABLE_FACES: "false"
  PHOTOPRISM_DISABLE_CLASSIFICATION: "false"
  PHOTOPRISM_DISABLE_RAW: "false"
  PHOTOPRISM_RAW_PRESETS: "false"
  PHOTOPRISM_JPEG_QUALITY: 85
  PHOTOPRISM_DETECT_NSFW: "false"
  PHOTOPRISM_UPLOAD_NSFW: "true"
  PHOTOPRISM_DATABASE_DRIVER: "mysql"
  PHOTOPRISM_DATABASE_SERVER: "mariadb:3306"
  PHOTOPRISM_DATABASE_NAME: "photoprism"
  PHOTOPRISM_DATABASE_USER: "photoprism"
  PHOTOPRISM_DATABASE_PASSWORD: "[redacted]"
  PHOTOPRISM_SITE_CAPTION: ""
  PHOTOPRISM_SITE_DESCRIPTION: ""
  PHOTOPRISM_SITE_AUTHOR: ""
working_dir: "/photoprism"

volumes:
  - "./Pictures:/photoprism/originals"

  - "./storage:/photoprism/storage"

mariadb:
restart: always
image: mariadb:10.8
security_opt:
  - seccomp:unconfined
  - apparmor:unconfined
command: mysqld --innodb-buffer-pool-size=512M --lower-case-table-names=1 --transaction-isolation=READ-COMMITTED --character-set-server=utf8mb4 --collation-server=utf8mb4_unicode_ci --max-connections=512 --innodb-rollback-on-timeout=OFF --innodb-lock-wait-timeout=120
volumes:
  - "./database:/var/lib/mysql"
environment:
  MARIADB_AUTO_UPGRADE: "1"
  MARIADB_INITDB_SKIP_TZINFO: "1"
  MARIADB_DATABASE: "photoprism"
  MARIADB_USER: "photoprism"
  MARIADB_PASSWORD: "[redacted]"
  MARIADB_ROOT_PASSWORD: "[redacted]"

volumes:
   database:
   driver: local
```

Comment: what is the name your  dir where the compose file located?

Comment: It's in the root folder of my drive.